# Return the corresponding SelectedValue of DropDownList in GridView after clicking the Button in GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am writing ASP.NET web forms in VB. I have a `GridView` which contains the following columns and rows:

```
 Product  |   Price   |   Quantity   |   Add to cart
iPhone 6  |   $6000   |(DropDownList)|    (Button)
iPhone 5  |   $5000   |(DropDownList)|    (Button)
```

The number of rows of this `GridView` depends on the `PRODUCT` table in the SQL Server Database.

The `Product` column gets `product_name` from the `PRODUCT` table.

The `Price` column gets `product_price` from the `PRODUCT` table.

The `TemplateField` column `Quantity` has a `DropDownList` (members: 1, 2, 3) on each row.

The `TemplateField` column `Add to cart` has a `Button` on each row.

**What I want to do**:

Clicking the `Button` on the `nth` row should only submit the `SelectedValue` of the `DropDownList` on the `nth` row.

I can use `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` if `DropDownList1` and the `Button` are not in `GridView` (they appear only once in the Web Form), but I don't know how I can do the same thing when they are in `GridView`.

My question is: how can I get the `SelectedValue` of the `DropDownList` in `GridView` in the simplest way?

Comment: How are you populating the gridview?

Comment: The Data Source of the `GridView` is a SQL Server Database stored in a `.mdf` file. The `GridView` is set to retrieve data from the database using the SQL query `SELECT * FROM product`. The two `TemplateField`s are added afterwards, to contain a `DropDownList` and a `Button` on each row of the `GridView`.

Comment: Hm... have you ever used a RepeateR?

Comment: No, I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code might help. 1st code block is for GridView , i am assuming you have used like this. Idea is to have an `TemplateField` and have gridview with `rowcommand` event set. `TemplateField` will have `LinkButton` ,having command name = `CartAdd`, and when `RowCommand` is fired, you get that event in 2nd code block and from there get corresponding selected value for `DropDownList`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvw" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            runat="server"  
            onrowcommand="gvw_RowCommand">

.... .
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View More">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCartAdd" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
            CommandName="CartAdd" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" />
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Next code block for code behind.

```
Protected Sub gvw_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "CartAdd" Then
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString())
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(gvw.Rows(index).FindControl("DDL_ID"), DropDownList) 'replce DDL_ID with required id used for dropdownlist
        Dim val As String = ddl.SelectedValue
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually is there any simpler method in doing this? Can I just have a line of code in a similar format like `DropDownList1.SelectedValue`? I expect to see something like `DropDownList[Row of Button].SelectedValue` (similar to array in programming). Please tell me if there is such expression in ASP.NET :P

Comment: If your design in purely JS driven, you can use Jquery selector to get that value directly in ASPX, else ,if you have serverside code, you have to go through this, else, how would you know, which row's button clicked, and which DDL to grab.

Comment: It appears to be containing errors if I am doing it correctly. One error message says `'GridViewRow' is a type and cannot be used as an expression`. I place the code block for code behind after the `Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` and it doesn't feel like I'm doing it right (some variables are underlined).

Comment: Ok, then skip this part `CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"` and try again, let me know errors, so that i can be helpful!

Comment: I know what goes wrong. I'm writing ASP.NET in VB but your code is in C#, I guess. Would you mind converting it into VB and I'll try it out :) Sorry and thank you for your help.

Comment: @blackr1234 , posted VB.net version, fixed one error, it should work now!

Comment: A runtime error occurs: `An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code`. It points to the line `Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString())`. Then if I add the `CommandArgument` part, it underlines `GridViewRow` and `Container`.

Comment: @blackr1234, Hey i have updated code, you need to have `CommandArgument` set. Earlier i told to remove, my bad!. I have updated code to have correct value. Code behind will remain same.It should work now.

Comment: It seems to be working, but I'm not sure how I can retrieve the variable `val` from the code behind to `<script> Sub func1() ... </script>` on the `.aspx` where I have written a `SqlCommand` to do an `INSERT INTO` function to modify the SQL Server Database based on the result (previously it's `DropDownList1.SelectedValue`, now how should I call the variable `val`?).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62895/discussion-between-arindam-nayak-and-blackr1234).

Comment: You can directly insert to DB from code behind RowCommand event.